# OFDM simulation in Simulink

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, simulink

The Orthogonal Frequency Division Multiplexing (OFDM) parameters are as follows:

Subcarriers: The baseband signal is composed of 512 orthogonal subcarriers.

Subcarrier Usage: Out of the 512 subcarriers, 496 carry data symbols, 6 are pilot tones used for correcting residual carrier frequency offset (cFO) caused by clock drift, and 10 are reserved carriers providing a guard band to prevent interference from carrier energy.

Cyclic Prefix: A cyclic prefix of 128 samples, which accounts for 25% of each OFDM word, is appended to every OFDM symbol. This helps capture Intersymbol Interference (ISI) caused by channel echoing.

Bit Loading: Each subcarrier can be loaded with a variable number of bits, ranging from 1 to 14 bits per subcarrier. This results in packet information rates varying from 496 to 6944 uncoded bits per OFDM symbol.

Symbol Rate: The OFDM symbols are transmitted at a rate of 7.81 kilosymbols per second (ksymbols/s).

Bandwidth: The transmission bandwidth is 5 megahertz (MHz), centered at a frequency of 8.3 MHz.

I just built the system on Simulink. I am having problem on receiver side, can't demodulate after Equalization block. Before that, I tried the system without the 8.3 MHz frequency conversion, it was working fine. Please tell me where I went wrong! May thanks[OFDM simulink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWeYL.png) [Constellation after Equalization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OA4Ta.png)

I tried the system without the 8.3 MHz frequency conversion, it was working fine. i think the problem is in the mixer part

Comment: here is constellation after equalization https://i.stack.imgur.com/OA4Ta.png

Comment: And here is OFDM system in Simulink https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWeYL.png